# Typescript - Object with any number of key values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying writing an interface to figure to handle data like this:

```
interface SessionList {
   appInfo: Object(string: string | null);
}
```

There could be 0 to many items under appInfo. I'm trying to find the correct syntax but not luck - currently at:

`appInfo: Object(string: string | null);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Either

```
interface AppInfo {
  [key: string]: string | null;
}
```

Or

```
Record<string, string | null>
```

Update:

```
let obj: { appInfo: Record<string, string | null> };

interface SessionList {
   appInfo: Record<string, string | null>;
}

let obj: SessionList;
```